# Showing error angular.js:12477 TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, intl-tel-input

I have a tab service provider which shows details of a customer. When you click the tab, it shows empty fields to edit and gives this error

> angular.js:12477 TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function

After refreshing the page, the error disappears. What could be the issue?

I have put my `intlTelInput` function inside a timeout function but it didn't work.

This is my code

```js
if ($("input[name='code']").length >= 1) {
    $("input[name='code']").intlTelInput({
        separateDialCode: true,
        initialCountry: "auto",
        geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
            $.getJSON("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
                callback(data.country_code); `
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This is the complete error

> angular.js:12477 TypeError: $(...).intlTelInput is not a function at
>   Object.
>   (http://localhost/taskm-rio/public/admin/app/ng-controllers/providerController.js:104:49)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAMmh.png)

Comment: Are you using `@types/ tel input`?

Comment: i am using intlTelInput,js

Comment: Why not use [`ng-intl-tel-input`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-intl-tel-input) instead? It's always better to use an angularjs solution if it's available than use a jquery one.

Answer (score 1):

Add utils.js in scripts,

```
`"scripts": [ 
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js"
            ]`
```

in angular.json file. This will solve your issue.

1. goto angular.json file
2. look for scripts
3. add "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js" inside the scripts along with the intlTelInput.min.js / intlTelInput.js
4. save
5. refresh your application